# Let $f$ be a differentiable function in $a$, which belongs to the real ones, find the limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, real-numbers

Let $f$ be a differentiable function in $a \in \Bbb R$ , find the limits

$$\lim_{x\to a} \left( \frac{f(x)e^x-f(a)}{f(x)cos(x)-f(a)} \right)$$ $a=0, f'(0) \ne 0$

and

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left( n\Big(f(a+\frac{1}{n})+f(a+\frac{2}{n}) + f(a+\frac{3}{n})+...+f(a+\frac{k}{n})-kf(a)\Big) \right)$$ $k \in N$

have any idea?

Comment: What leads you to believe these limits exist?

Comment: If $a=0$ why not just write $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way to tackle this is to remember that differentiability of $f$ at $a=0$ means

- $(\star)$: $f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x+o(x)$ where $o(x)$ represents a remainder with the property that $\frac{o(x)}{x} \stackrel{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}0$.

Besides this note that $e^x$ and $\cos x$ are differentiable and we have

- $(\star\star)$: $\frac{e^x-1}{x} \stackrel{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}e^0=1$ and $\frac{\cos x-1}{x} \stackrel{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}-\sin 0 = 0$

Applying this to your first limit you get:

\begin{eqnarray}\frac{f(x)e^x-f(0)}{f(x)\cos(x)-f(0)}
& \stackrel{(\star)}{=} & \frac{f(0)(e^x-1) + (f'(0)x+o(x))e^x}{f(0)(\cos(x)-1)+(f'(0)x+o(x))\cos(x)} \\
& = & \frac{f(0)\overbrace{\frac{e^x-1}{x}}^{\stackrel{x\to 0}{\rightarrow}1} + (f'(0)+\frac{o(x)}{x})e^x}{f(0)\underbrace{\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}}_{\stackrel{x\to 0}{\rightarrow}0}+(f'(0)+\frac{o(x)}{x})\cos(x)}\\
& \stackrel{(\star\star): x\to 0}{\rightarrow} & \frac{f(0) + f'(0)}{f'(0)} = \boxed{1+ \frac{f(0)}{f'(0)}}
\end{eqnarray}

For the second (surely you mean $n\to \infty$) just note that

- $(\star\star\star)$: The finite sum of several $o(x)$ and constant multiples of $o(x)$ produce just another $o(x)$.

\begin{eqnarray} n \left(\sum_{i=1}^k f\left(\frac in\right) - kf(0)\right)
& = & n\sum_{i=1}^k  \left(f\left(\frac in\right) - f(0)\right) \\
& \stackrel{(\star)}{=} & n\sum_{i=1}^k  \left(f'(0) \frac in + o\left(\frac in\right)\right) \\
& \stackrel{(\star\star\star)}{=} & f'(0)\sum_{i=1}^k i + \underbrace{no\left(\frac 1n\right)}_{= \frac{o\left(\frac 1n\right)}{\frac 1n}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0} \\
& \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} & \boxed{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}f'(0)}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

Here is an elementary solution without using taylor series:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{f(x)e^x-f(0)}{f(x)\cos(x)-f(0)} \right)$$
$$ = \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{f(x)e^x-f(x)}{x}\right)+\left(\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{f(x)\cos x-f(x)}{x}\right)+\left(\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\right)}$$
$$=\dfrac{f(0)+f'(0)}{0+f'(0)}$$
$$=1+\dfrac{f(0)}{f'(0)}$$

**Solution of second part**

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left( n(f(\frac{1}{n})+f(\frac{2}{n}) + f(\frac{3}{n})+...+f(\frac{k}{n})-kf(0)) \right)$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sum_{r=1}^k\Bigg(f\Big(\dfrac{r}{n}\Big)-f(0)\Bigg)$$
$$ = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^k\Bigg(\dfrac{f\Big(\dfrac{r}{n}\Big)-f(0)}{\dfrac{r}{n}}\times r\Bigg)$$
$$=\sum_{r=1}^k\Bigg( r\times\lim_{\frac{r}{n}\to0}\dfrac{f\Big(\dfrac{r}{n}\Big)-f(0)}{\dfrac{r}{n}}\Bigg)$$
$$=f'(0)\sum_{r=1}^k r$$
$$=\dfrac{k(k+1)}{2}f'(0)$$

Answer (score 2):

Noting
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^xf(x)-f(0)}{x}=(e^xf(x))'|_{x=0}=e^xf(x)+e^xf'(x)|_{x=0}=f(0)+f'(0) $$
and
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)\cos x-f(0)}{x}=(f(x)\cos x)'|_{x=0}=f'(x)-f(x)\sin x|_{x=0}=f'(0) $$
one has
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)e^x-f(0)}{f(x)\cos(x)-f(0)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{f(x)e^x-f(0)}{x}}{\frac{f(x)\cos(x)-f(0)}{x}}=\frac{f(0)+f'(0)}{f'(0)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can make it composing Taylor series.

Assuming first that $a \neq 0$
$$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a) f'(a)+O\left((x-a)^2\right)$$
$$f(x)e^x=e^a f(a)+e^a (x-a) \left(f'(a)+f(a)\right)+O\left((x-a)^2\right)$$
$$f(x)\cos(x)=f(a) \cos (a)+(x-a) \left(\cos (a) f'(a)-f(a) \sin (a)\right)+O\left((x-a)^2\right)$$ Now, make the long division to get
$$\frac{f(x)e^x-f(a)}{f(x)\cos(x)-f(a)}=\frac{e^a-1}{\cos (a)-1}+A (x-a)+O\left((x-a)^2\right)$$ where
$$A=\frac{\left(\cos (a)-e^a\right) f'(a)+f(a) \left(e^a (\sin (a)+\cos (a)-1)-\sin
   (a)\right)}{f(a) (\cos (a)-1)^2}$$

If $a=0$, this would write
$$\frac{f(x)e^x-f(0)}{f(x)\cos(x)-f(0)}=\left(1+\frac{f(0)}{f'(0)}\right)+\frac{ \left(-f(0) f''(0)+2 f(0) f'(0)+2
   f'(0)^2+f(0)^2\right)}{2 f'(0)^2}x+O\left(x^3\right)$$